# How to set the background color for a layout element in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to set the background color of both columns left/right.

I thought columns/rows have similar meaning/functionality like bootstrap in web development.

But it seems everything is more laborious...

Please do not tell me I have to wrap each Expanded with the Container widget and set there the color...

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("left", textAlign: TextAlign.end,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 7,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "right",
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[],
    )
  ]),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `container` has the property `color` then you need to wrap the `column` widget with a `container` to change its color:

```
Expanded(
  flex: 3,
  child: Container(
    color : Colors.black,
    child : Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("left", textAlign: TextAlign.end,),
      ],
    ),
  )
),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the text align does not work? Its always centered ???

Comment: you can use the following for example `child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("left", textAlign: TextAlign.end,),
                       Text("lda", textAlign: TextAlign.end,),
                    ],
                  ),`